# Use WM_SETTEXT to replace contents of window whilst maintaining window scroll position

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage

I'm building an application that sends RTF text to a third-party window. It basically provides auto-correct functionality within a primitive third-party IDE.

I can set the contents of this window (i.e. the corrected code), but doing so sets the window's scroll position to the top. This is very annoying because then the user has to scroll down to where they were before the autocorrect kicked in.

I can set the cursor to the correct position (down on the page), but this doesn't prevent the window from scrolling to the top.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you just replace what's needed using EM_REPLACESEL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WM_SETTEXT` is the wrong message to use when replacing a small portion of the text. You use `WM_SETTEXT` to set the entire text content of the control.

What you want is to select the word that needs to be corrected. Use `EM_SETSEL` for that. And then use `EM_REPLACESEL` to replace the text with the corrected version. I expect that will also have the happy effect of fixing the problem of unwanted scrolling.

Comment: Thanks! Once I worked out that I had to insert with the {\rtf etc. markup it's worked well. Still have to see if it gets around my scrolling issue but I suspect you're right and it will resolve the issue.